# Dataproc: PySpark logging to GCS Bucket

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-dataproc, python-logging, google-cloud-storage

I have a pyspark job running in Dataproc. Currently, we are logging to console/yarn logs. As per our requirement, we need to store the logs in GCS bucket. Is there a way to directly log to files in GCS Bucket with python logging module?

I have tried to set the logging module with below config. But it's throwing an error (FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: '/gs:/bucket_name/newfile.log')

`logging.basicConfig(filename="gs://bucket_name/newfile.log", format='%(asctime)s %(message)s', filemode='w')`

Comment: Is cloud logging sink to Cloud Storage an option?

Comment: @guillaumeblaquiere definitely, can this be achieved with cloud logging?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default, `yarn:yarn.log-aggregation-enable` is set to true and `yarn:yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir` is set to `gs://<cluster-tmp-bucket>/<cluster-uuid>/yarn-logs` on Dataproc 1.5+, so YARN container logs are aggregated in the GCS dir, but you can update it with

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create ... \
  --properties yarn:yarn.nodemanager.remote-app-log-dir=<gcs-dir>
```

or update the tmp bucket of the cluster with

```
gcloud dataproc clusters create ... --temp-bucket <bucket>
```

Note that

- If your Spark job is in **client** mode (the default), the Spark driver runs on master node instead of in YARN, driver logs are stored in the Dataproc-generated job property `driverOutputResourceUri` which is a job specific folder in the cluster's staging bucket. Otherwise, in **cluster** mode, the Spark driver runs in YARN, the driver logs are YARN container logs and are aggregated as described above.
- If you want to disable Cloud Logging for your cluster, set `dataproc:dataproc.logging.stackdriver.enable=false`. But note that it will disable **all** types of Cloud Logging logs including YARN container logs, startup and service logs.